# Get total count of users from AspNetUser table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an admin page where I wish to show different statistics - including the total count of users created.

According to SQL Server Management Studio the table `AspNetUser` contains all the users created on my site. I am using Entity Framework but surely the `DbContext` does not contain this table. So - how do I count the amount of users from this table?

I have been trying the following but with no luck.

```
Membership.GetAllUsers().Count()
```

I get the following error at "GetAllUsers()" before compiletime:
[image]

I am not sure if the use of Membership is the correct way to achieve what I want? There might be another way to get the total count of users?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Do you get an error? Any results at all? Compile time error? what do you mean by `with no luck`

Comment: Why can't you drop the table onto the designer if its not in the context already?

Comment: Hi Austin - I have edited my question with the error that I receive.

Comment: Yes - embarassing - I just noticed that. (I have edited the screenshot).

Comment: You could run a loop through the ASPNetUsers Table and pull out the high id value, or you could count the number of records in the ASPNetUsers table, either would work. If you provide more code/repository (The M, V, and C) then i could get you a specific answer.

Comment: Thank you Joseph - a loop sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers()` returns a [`MembershipUserCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipusercollection_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

It does not implement a `.Count()` method but does have a `.Count` property.

```
int count = Membership.GetAllUsers().Count;
```

However, if you are creating a new default MVC5 application (VS2013) you are likely using the newer membership API (Identity Framework) and the above code would not likely work.

In the `AccountController` there will be an `AppicationUserManager UserManager` property and you can do the following:

```
int count = UserManager.Users.Count();
```

Comment: I tried this but I receive the following error: `An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.` I have proper connection to my database though.

Comment: `Unable to connect to SQL Server database` clearly means there *is not* a proper connection to the database.

Comment: Are you using the correct membership API? This would not be valid if you are not implementing the same membership framework? See the "background" section [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

Comment: I have been reading up on the link you gave me and I am not sure if I understood it correctly, but I am using .OWIN and not .CORE in this MVC setup. Could that be the reason why `MembershipUserCollection users;` returns `null`?

Comment: If that's the case, and based on the name of your table, then you are likely using [Identity Framework](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) with the authentication module built as OWIN middleware. The reason you are getting errors with the `System.Web.Security` is that is part of the old membership API and are missing some parts in your project.

Comment: If you are using Identity then your _packages.config_ will contain `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example:
 [MembershipUserCollection.Count Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipusercollection.count(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 MembershipUserCollection users;
 int NumUsers;
 users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
 NumUsers = users.Count;
```

Comment: I tried this aswell and I am still getting the same error as mentioned above. `MembershipUserCollection users;` returns `null`.

Comment: Do you have the SQLmemberprovider configured in your web.config file? If so ensure you are pointing to the correct database .